# WPF Popup with ListView and GridView not resizing when content has changed

Tags: wpf, autolayout, popup, resize

Despite searching for a similar situation I could not find anything comparable to automaticaly resizing a popup content depending on its content.

Eventually I missed something obvious but after being created, my popup stubornly refuses to recalculate its size and content layout when the content changes.

To be more precise: my popup hosts a ListView which content changes dynamically.

Now when the popup is first created it's width will accomodate to the desired size of the ListView so that all list view elements (inside a GridView).

[image: Initial Popup created properly]

When now the elements in the ListView update, the width of the longest element changes. The expected behaviour is that the list view and the popup will change size (width) to match the new list elements.

Unfortunately the Popup and its content just refuse to change and as a conscequence the content gets cropped.

[image: Height does change, but width just refuses to update]

I already tryed to invalidate popup arrangement and measure, and called UpdateLayout of the Popup and/or the ListView, without success so far... The GridView element I could not access/manage it...

Is there a way to force a total layout recompute of the Popup or ListView?

```
<Popup x:Name           = "hintPopup"
       Placement        = "Bottom"
       PlacementTarget  = "{Binding ElementName=textBox}"
       MinWidth         = "{Binding ElementName=textBox, Path=ActualWidth}"
       IsOpen           = "{Binding ShowPopup, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ccont:vokDataGridEdit}}"
       Margin           = "0,20,0,0">

    <!-- Reference a converter to convert Bool Values to Visibility -->
    <Popup.Resources>
        <conv:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter" />
    </Popup.Resources>

    <!-- Move popup with anchor -->
    <b:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behav:PopupAutoRepositionBehavior />
    </b:Interaction.Behaviors>

    <Border BorderBrush     = "Gray" 
            BorderThickness = "1"
            Background      = "LightGray"
            Padding         = "1">

        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">

            <!-- Title Starts With -->
            <TextBlock Text         = "{x:Static res:Strings.vokDataGridEdit_Popup_TitleStartsWith}"
                       Visibility   = "{Binding ShowHintsStartsWith, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ccont:vokDataGridEdit}, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=collapsed}"
                       FontWeight   = "Bold"
                       Foreground   = "Black"
                       Margin       = "0, 5, 0, 2"/>

            <!-- Hints -->
            <ListView ItemsSource   = "{Binding ItemHintsStartsWith, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ccont:vokDataGridEdit}}"
                      Visibility    = "{Binding ShowHintsStartsWith, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ccont:vokDataGridEdit}, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=collapsed}"
                      Margin        = "5, 1, 1, 1">

                <!-- Prevent selection -->
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

                <!-- Hide Headers -->
                <ListView.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    </Style>
                </ListView.Resources>

                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">

                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding    = "{Binding Path=valueCurrent}" 
                                        Header                  = "Current"
                                        Width                   = "auto" />

                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding    = "{Binding Path=valueTranslated}" 
                                        Header                  = "Translated"
                                        Width                   = "auto" />

                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>

            </ListView>

            <!-- Title Similar -->
            <TextBlock Text         = "{x:Static res:Strings.vokDataGridEdit_Popup_Similar}"
                       Visibility   = "{Binding ShowHintsSimilar, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ccont:vokDataGridEdit}, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=collapsed}"
                       FontWeight   = "Bold"
                       Foreground   = "Black"
                       Margin       = "0, 5, 0, 2"/>

            <!-- Hints -->
            <ListView ItemsSource   = "{Binding ItemHintsSimilar, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ccont:vokDataGridEdit}}"
                      Visibility    = "{Binding ShowHintsSimilar, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ccont:vokDataGridEdit}, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=collapsed}"
                      Margin        = "5, 1, 1, 1">

                <!-- Prevent selection -->
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

                <!-- Hide Headers -->
                <ListView.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    </Style>
                </ListView.Resources>

                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">

                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding    = "{Binding Path=valueCurrent}" 
                                        Header                  = "Current"
                                        Width                   = "auto" />

                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding    = "{Binding Path=valueTranslated}" 
                                        Header                  = "Translated"
                                        Width                   = "auto" />

                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>

            </ListView>

        </StackPanel>

    </Border>

</Popup>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, finally I found the solution while working on another `GridView` enabled `ListView` in the project. Actually the `GridView` is causing the issue as it will not automatically resize the columns when elements in the bound collection change.

I, therefore, implemented a `Behavior` that will trigger a resizing event whenever the collection the `ListView` is bound to changes:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Adds auto resizing to a ListView GridViews columns
/// </summary>
public class GridViewColumnAutoResizeBehavior : BehaviorBase<ListView>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Setup the behavior
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        // Associate handler
        if (this.AssociatedObject?.Items is INotifyCollectionChanged notifyingCollection)
        {
            notifyingCollection.CollectionChanged += this.OnCollectionChanged;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handler to force resizing the columns
    /// </summary>
    private void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs notifyCollectionChangedEventArgs)
    {
        if (this.AssociatedObject.View is GridView gridView)
        {
            // Resize automatic columns
            foreach (GridViewColumn gridViewColumn in gridView.Columns.Where(column => double.IsNaN(column.Width)))
            {
                gridViewColumn.Width = gridViewColumn.ActualWidth;
                gridViewColumn.Width = double.NaN;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean-up the behavior
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnCleanup()
    {
        // Clean-up handler
        if (this.AssociatedObject?.Items is INotifyCollectionChanged notifyingCollection)
        {
            notifyingCollection.CollectionChanged -= this.OnCollectionChanged;
        }

        base.OnCleanup();
    }
}
```

Be sure to use a collection that implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` for the behavior to attach.

The code uses an auto-detaching behavior, so you would need to adapt to the base class you are using, which should be straight forward.